# Closest Date in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, closest

I am trying to find nearest date or actual date between `Table_A` and `Table_B` in SQL Server 2012

Table_A

```
Date
-------
2017-07-15 00:00:00
2017-07-27 00:00:00
2017-07-23 00:00:00
```

Table_B

```
DT
------
2017-07-17 00:00:00
2017-07-19 00:00:00
2017-07-23 00:00:00
2017-07-28 00:00:00
```

Conditions:

- If Table_A.Date = Table_B.DT then Table_A.Date
- If table_A.Date <> Table_B.DT then whichever next higher date in Table_B

Desired output:

```
Date
-----
2017-07-17 00:00:00
2017-07-23 00:00:00
2017-07-28 00:00:00
```

Any help or guidance?

Comment: MSSQL Server 2012

Comment: do you have any sql you've tried yet?

Comment: i made query for first condition, but for second one I am not able to make concept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `CROSS APPLY` and `TOP`:

```
SELECT 
    Date = x.DT
FROM Table_A a
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP(1) DT
    FROM Table_B b
    WHERE b.DT >= a.Date
    ORDER BY b.DT
) x
ORDER BY x.DT
```